# Custom traverse logic for tree

Tags: swift

I have a flat list which I convert to tree with this code

```
class Node {
    var Children: [Node] = []
    weak var parent: Node?
    weak var nextObject: Node?
    var associatedObject: AppListItem?

    init(associatedObject: AppListItem) {
        self.associatedObject = associatedObject
    }
}

func getRootsFrom(list: [AppListItem]) -> [Node] {
    var dict: [String : Node] = [:]
    list.forEach { (appItem) in
        dict[appItem.uuid] = Node(associatedObject: appItem)
    }
    dict.values.forEach { (node) in
        var proposedParent: Node
        if let value = dict[node.associatedObject?.parentUUID ?? ""] {
            proposedParent = value
            node.parent = proposedParent
            proposedParent.Children.append(node)
            proposedParent.Children.sort(by: {$0.associatedObject?.sort ?? "" < $1.associatedObject?.sort ?? ""})
            proposedParent.nextObject = proposedParent.Children.first
        }
    }
    return dict.values.filter({$0.parent == nil}).sorted(by: {$0.associatedObject?.sort ?? "" < $1.associatedObject?.sort ?? ""})
}
```

where `getRootsFrom` converts list to tree, and returns roots, and I have a problem with correctly marking nextObject for each object.

[image]

so next Object should be

> beverages -> cold -> milk -> soda -> bitter lemon -> ginger ale

and after this it should go to

> hot

and etc...

I am not quite sure that my code do it correctly, its only marks until first leaf and after that nextObject becomes nil

Thanks for helping.

Comment: You need to build the tree first. Then do a depth-first traversal to fill in the `nextObject` for each node. You can't populate `nextObject` until the tree if fully built.

Comment: Thanks rmaddy, I reseached little bit about depth-first traversal, but didnt quite understand it,is there any example of doing this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're already building the tree so getting it into a list should be fairly straight forward. Based on your image, it looks like you want to get an array using a [pre order traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Pre-order_(NLR)). First I'd add the filling method to `Node`

```
func preorder() -> [Node] {
    return [self] + Children.flatMap { $0.preorder() }
}
```

Then in `getRootsFrom` change the return to be

```
return dict.values.first(where: {$0.parent == nil})?.preorder() ?? []
```

The [wikipedia article on tree traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversa) is a great source to read about it. It show the different orderings with images and pseudocode.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I need.